# Why can't I drop a table on MYsql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the code:

```
USE new_schema;
DROP TABLE account;
ALTER TABLE transaction
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_t_account_id;
```

the error:

> 09:10:05   DROP TABLE account  Error Code: 3730. Cannot drop table 'account' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'fk_t_account_id' on table 'transaction'.  0.000 sec

Comment: You need to drop the foreign key *before* you attempt to drop the table it refers to

Answer (score 0):

Looks at the foreign key.  That table also needs to be dropped or remove the foreign key constraint

Just switch the order of the SQL

```
USE new_schema;

ALTER TABLE transaction
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_t_account_id;

DROP TABLE account;
```